# Font type of text inside Ctrl+F FIND textbox of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, fonts, ide, find, android-theme

I have changed the font of:

File | Settings | Editor | Font

File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font

File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Color Scheme Font


All above **does not** affect the font type inside **textbox of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> FIND** of Android Studio

Screenshot below prooved that 2 different fonts comparing 2 of my PC's in Windows 10. The Editor's font is working fine. But not FIND box.

- **I've even Export/Import Settings from/to both PC does not affecting at all. So this means that this is something to do outside of Android Studio or THEME config.**
- **I've also Restarted PC**

---

### **So any expert who can help on guiding config files changes will highly appreciated.**

[image][image][image][image] [image]

Answer (score -1):

FIND box is related to Appearance. Go to Settings->Appearance & Behaviour->Appearance use custom font and size.